# How to remove a shortcut from applications menu - Freya

Tags: slingshot, app-shortcuts

I need to remove an unnecessary shortcut from the applications menu. How do I remove it.

My question is not to hide a shortcut.  I need to remove an icon or shortcut from the menu. not hiding it. 
This is not duplicate question. Please understand the difference between hiding and removing of an icon.

Comment: I am not asking help to hide it.  I need to remove it.

Comment: What's the difference between hiding and removing?

Comment: Are you asking how to uninstall an application?

Answer (score 3):

Use Mainmenu (AKA `alacarte`)

Install from software center or with terminal command:

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

[image: img]

Comment: Let me test it.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is MenuLibre

```
sudo apt-get install menulibre
```